# How To Use JSON Returned From a URL in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I have a URL which returns JSON data. I would then like to use some parts of this data in Javascript. At the moment I'm getting an 'Uncaught Syntax Error' in the console when I run it.

My code looks like this:

```
var myAPIcall = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=SW1A1AA&callback=?";


$.get(myAPIcall, function( data ) {
    console.log("Place ID = " + data.results.place_id);
}, "json" );
```

It's the JSON itself which is causing the error.

How can I get the JSON (specifically the place_id, but I'd be happy with any of it) to display with the `console.log`? If I understand that much I should then be able to move on and use the place_id in my code.

Thanks

Comment: try `data.results[0].place_id` since `results` is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check our query. Removing `callback=?` will result in a valid JSON :-)

```js
var myAPIcall = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=SW1A1AA";


    $.getJSON(myAPIcall, function( data ) {
        console.log(data.results[0].place_id);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```